# Is this usage of const_cast undefined in practice?

Tags: c++, constants

I have a class that manages input.  To display and alter key bindings, it's important to give a caller a map of the bindings it can own and alter, before committing it to the manager when done.    However, there are specific rules on what can be inserted/removed in this map that only the manager knows, thus the caller must be forced to ask the manager to make changes.

The caller gets a `const` version of the map to insure it cannot modify it on it's own, while the manager can still alter the map using a `const_cast`

```
typedef std::multimap<Key, Input> Map;

class InputManager{
    public:

    const Map getBindings(){
        // builds the map and returns it
    }

    bool insertBinding(const Map & bindings, Key key, Input input){
        // performs the insert after checking several rules first
        if(rulesAllowIt){
            const_cast<Map&>(bindings).insert(std::make_pair(key, input));
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    void commitBindings(const Map & bindings){
        // commits the bindings to replace the old
    }
}
```

This currently works as expected, but I'm worried by the usage of `const_cast`, since modifying a `const` variable is UB in principle (unless there are exceptions?)

In practice, will this cause UB, or any other subtle performance problems or bugs on different platforms or compilers, or conflict with possible optimizations?

Comment: Why doesn't the manager store the map itself? This would solve all of your problems.

Comment: Is the map being passed in `const` or not?

Comment: The answer to "UB or not"  question depends on the constness of the object `bindings` is bound to. It is not clear from the code you posted. It is not clear what object will be used as an argument in the call.

Comment: Why use a `const` reference if you're going to change it? That's just a lie!

Comment: What does "in practice" mean? Is there any *other* way to write computer programs?

Comment: @tobspr - The returned map is a transformed version that has the keys/values swapped.  Also, it might be necessary to store multiple of them in the caller, one to display and one to edit

Comment: @AnneQuinn: I don't understand the logic of your code. You pass someone an object, which they now *own* (since it's a value type). But you declare it `const`, so that they can't modify it. Even though they can simply copy it to another variable and modify *that*. What's the point? Indeed, they can just do `Map data = obj.getBindings();`, and never see the `const`.

Comment: @FredLarson - My bad!!  I'll just remove all the const qualifiers and tell the caller to not mess with it using a comment, then it's their fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const Map getBindings()` is a fairly pointless return type. The user can in any case write code this:

```
Map foo = manager.getBindings();
manager.insertBinding(foo, key, whatever);
foo.clear();
manager.commitBindings(foo);
```

In which case the code has defined behavior (at least, up to the point where `commitBindings` probably isn't expecting to see an empty map). Alternatively they could write this:

```
const Map foo = manager.getBindings();
manager.insertBinding(foo, key, whatever);
manager.commitBindings(foo);
```

In which case the code has UB per the standard. One way in which it could fail *in practice*, is that the optimizer is entitled to assume that since `foo` is `const`-qualified at the point where it is defined, then the values of its non-`mutable` data members will not change. Therefore, after inlining the code of `commitBindings`, it could re-order accesses to `foo` so that a data member is read *before* the call to `insertBinding` that results in it being modified.

In practice it doesn't seem like this is happening to your `Map`, but it's one reason why modifying `const`-qualified objects can become more than just a theoretical problem.

To get where you want to be, you could add another level of indirection (compile-time indirection: the compiler can remove the overheads). Define a class that has the `Map` as a private data member, and whose only public mutator has the same effect as `insertBinding`. Then the user has no means to modify the `Map` other than via the code that checks the rules. For efficiency, make sure that your class has a working move constructor and move assignment, since copying a `std::multimap` can be a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

This looks to me a bit like a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Although it will work the reality is that you've declared your `insertBindings` method to take a constant map, and yet you're not honoring the const-ness within the method.

If you're going to potentially modify the map then just declare the type as non-const so that the method behaves in a way everyone would expect.

Comment: If the parameter is non-const, the caller can't pass the map back to it without casting it away first, which defeats the idea that the caller shouldn't be able to alter it directly

Comment: ***the caller can't pass the map back to it without casting it away first*** Why? You have it declared as const & inside the caller?

Comment: @AnneQuinn - you say the caller shouldn't be able to alter it, buy maybe they are breaking the rules and casting away the const like you are..!!